# MarkLogic Xquery

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I am in need of using corb to generate a report.

```
Data:
Collection A : Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
Collecntion B: Col1,Col5,Col6,Col7
Collection C: Col1,Col8,Col9

Output Requirement: Col1,Col2,Col5,Col6,Col8
```

where Col1 is in a way an inner join in Collections B,C

My `uri.xqy`looks like this:

```
(:Get the list from Col1 to join on all:)
let $listFromCol1 := cts:element-values(xs:QName("Col1"),(),(),cts:and-query(....))

let $A := cts:uris((),(),cts:and-query((cts:collection-query("A"),cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("Col1"),"=",$ListFromCol1)))
let $B := cts:uris((),(),cts:and-query((cts:collection-query("B"),cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("Col1"),"=",$ListFromCol1)))
let $C := cts:uris((),(),cts:and-query((cts:collection-query("C"),cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("Col1"),"=",$ListFromCol1)))
```

Now, I got the URIs for individual collections. I need to pass this to my `process.xqy` in `return (count($uris), $uris)`.

I wonder how do I get the count of all $A,$B,$C and concat all URIs of $A,$B,$C.

Please help

Comment: You want to iterate over Col1 values, not uris. Does Corb allow you to return Col1 values as if they were uris? If you then do a cts:search on col1 you get all docs in one blow related to that record, and can construct the record you need for your report. Otherwise it becomes a bit more complicated..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately,what you suggested works only for a small set of records. When I try to create an xml element with nodes from each of A,B,C ..ML doesnt work. Hence CoRB. And, I believe CoRB needs URIs to be supplied to Process.xqy

Comment: Did you try? ;-)

Comment: Yes. It ran for 45mins and stopped just like that. Hence I swithced to CoRB.

Comment: You just want a distinct list of the URIs that are in $A, $B, $C? Why not combine them into a single query with each of the collections specified in the `cts:collection-query()`? like this: `cts:uris((),(),cts:and-query((cts:collection-query( ("A", "B", "C") ),cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("Col1"),"=",$ListFromCol1)))`

Comment: Other ways to turn those sets of URIs into one distinct list would be `let $uris := distinct-values( ($A, $B, $C) )`, or use maps: `let $uris := map:keys( map:new( ($A, $B, $C) ! map:entry(.,.) ) )`

Comment: Thank you. Those are some workable solutions. However, all of them seem to be resource intense operations!? I am running this query over around 10Mil documents. May be I should split my uri,process query over separate sets of A, B &C

Comment: Is the desired output simply a distinct list of URIs? CoRB has options for EXPORT-FILE-SORT where you can specify `EXPORT-FILE-SORT=ascending|distinct` when used in combination with `PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask` and   
`EXPORT-FILE-NAME=/local/path/to/exportFile.txt`

Comment: Also, if you have 10s of millions of URIs, you might also want to enable the `DISK-QUEUE` option, in order to avoid blowing your JVM memory.

Comment: Thank you.DISK-QUEUE is a very good option. I have tried to use A in uri query and using those uris, I worked out B,C in process query. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a solution -- @MadsHansen, can you write that up as an answer so it's easy for people to see that this problem has been addressed?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extremely large set of URIs, then you may want to enable the **DISK-QUEUE** option.

`DISK-QUEUE=true` will avoid Out of Memory exceptions by allowing CORB to spill over to disk when receiving and managing the queue of URIs returned from the uris.xqy, instead of holding them all in memory.

If you need to get a distinct set of URIs in your output, you could return all of the URI candidates in your process module and let CORB do the de-duping by using `EXPORT-FILE-SORT=ascending|distinct` option with the *ExportBatchToFileTask*.

Example properties enabling those options:

```
DISK-QUEUE=true
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=/local/path/to/exportFile.txt
EXPORT-FILE-SORT=ascending|distinct
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileT‌​ask
```